# Prevent drop down list options scrolling on Windows in SWT

Tags: java, windows, drop-down-menu, scroll, swt

One of the drop down lists in my Java SWT application has 8 fixed options. When I click on it only 5 first options are visible and I have to scroll the list down to view the rest.

Is there any way to force it to make all options visible without having to scroll down?

There is another similar .NET application that has same drop down list with the same options and they all are visible without having to scroll down!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah.. apparently there is a `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo.setVisibleItemCount(int)` method that works on Windows. That was easier then I initially thought.